# Register COM dll on windows server 2008 64-bit

Tags: asp.net, com, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I'm trying to reference a COM dll from my ASP.NET Web API site running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Service Pack 1 64-bit using IIS 7.5.

I can register the COM dll on my Windows 7 64-bit machine and IIS has no problems referencing it.

I have tried registering the dll using the following command on the Windows Server 2008 box using the following command:

```
c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe <filename>.dll
```

I get the message that it has registered successfully, but when I run the web site I get the following exception:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

I've tried restarting IIS.

I've seen the [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/168e08cc-b553-4c69-9917-1e142f5ca7c6/), but re-installing windows is not the optimum solution.

1. Any thoughts on what could be causing this problem?
2. Also, why is Windows 7 working and Windows Server 2008 not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to edit the Advanced Settings of the app pool in IIS.  Then on that dialog set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to true.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's related to a 64-bit OS?  Check here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282747

Comment: I don't get an error when I register the dll.  It registers successfully, but ASP.Net says it is not registered.  I tried using the regsvr32 in the c:\windows\syswow64\ directory, but still received the same error message.